# Can all meromorphic functions be described by analytic parametrizations?

Tags: complex-analysis, parametrization, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Since every meromorphic function $f(z)$ can be written as the quotient of two holomorphic functions, I was wondering whether one can also describe $(z,f(z))$ as parametrized by two analytic functions $(z(t), f(t))$?

As an example, note how $f(z)=1/z$ can be obtained from $z(t)=e^t$ and $f(t)=e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example worked fine because there was only one singularity at $z=0$ that could be shifted to infinity by letting $z(t)=e^t$. However, as a result of the ["Little" Picard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) any second singularity could not be omitted, so the answer is:

No, only <s>meromorphic</s><sup>$\dagger$</sup> functions with *one* singularity (or none, of course) can be parametrized by analytic functions.

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup> Actually, even functions with one *essential* singularity or inverse functions can be described this way, e.g.

- $f(t)=t, z(t)=e^t$ for $f(z)=\ln z$
- $f(t)=t,z(t)=t^2$ for $f(z)=\sqrt z$
- $f(t)=\sin e^{-t}, z(t)=e^t$ for $f(z) = \sin 1/z$.

Comment: ...although I somehow hoped shifting multiple singularities to $|t| = \infty$ were possible. I'm not sure how well Picard plays with infinity.